# How can I query the count of the intersection of IDs from two different join tables

Tags: sql, elixir, ecto

I have a few models. User, Track, Playlist, UserTrack, and PlaylistTrack. A User can have many tracks, as can a Playlist. I want to query Playlists with the most tracks that match a User's UserTracks.

Here's how I'm doing it now:

```
user_tracks = # get all track_ids for a user in the users_tracks join table

playlists =
  from(p in Playlist,
    join: pt in PlaylistTrack,
    where: pt.playlist_id == p.id,
    having:
      fragment(
        "cardinality(array(
              select unnest(array_agg(?)::varchar[])
              intersect
              select unnest(?::varchar[])
            )) > 0",
        pt.track_id,
        ^user_tracks
      ),
    group_by: p.id,
    order_by:
      fragment(
        "cardinality(array(
              select unnest(array_agg(?)::varchar[])
              intersect
              select unnest(?::varchar[])
            )) DESC",
        pt.track_id,
        ^user_tracks
      ),
    limit: ^limit,
    select: p
  )
```

This works but is quite slow, is there a better way to write this query?

In short: "If we have table `users`, with many assocs in join-table `user_tracks`, that link to `tracks`. Order items in table `playlists` by the amount of assocs they have with table `tracks` in common with `users`'s assocs in table `tracks`"

Comment: Example data and result can make more clear your question.

Comment: Check this out: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/994fc/3/0. You can manipulate a number of joins with previously fetched queries

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with making an optimal raw SQL query, then look if / how it can be translated to Ecto.

Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE playlist_tracks (playlist_id integer, track_id integer);
CREATE TABLE playlists (id integer, title character varying);
CREATE TABLE user_tracks (user_id integer, track_id integer);

INSERT INTO user_tracks VALUES (1, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (1, 10);
INSERT INTO playlist_tracks VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 9), (4, 10), (4, 11), (5, 10), (5, 11), (5, 12);
INSERT INTO playlists VALUES (1, 'Classic Rock''s Greatest Hits'),
                             (2, 'Kings & Queens of Blues Rock'),
                             (3, 'Mojito Lounge'),
                             (4, 'Dark Electro Lounging'),
                             (5, 'Atmospheric Chilled Electronica');
```

The query I arrived at looks like this:

```
  SELECT p.id,
         p.title
    FROM playlists p
    JOIN playlist_tracks pt on p.id = pt.playlist_id
    JOIN user_tracks ut on pt.track_id = ut.track_id
   WHERE ut.user_id = 1
GROUP BY p.id,
         p.title
ORDER BY count(1) DESC;
```

Note that you do not need to join `users` table here.

Running `explain analyse ...` on the query returns the following:

```
                                                                  QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=150.61..151.11 rows=200 width=44) (actual time=0.131..0.131 rows=5 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(1)) DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=140.97..142.97 rows=200 width=44) (actual time=0.119..0.121 rows=5 loops=1)
         Group Key: p.id, p.title
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=82.25..135.05 rows=789 width=36) (actual time=0.104..0.108 rows=15 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (p.id = pt.playlist_id)
               ->  Seq Scan on playlists p  (cost=0.00..22.70 rows=1270 width=36) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=5 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=80.70..80.70 rows=124 width=4) (actual time=0.073..0.073 rows=15 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=38.39..80.70 rows=124 width=4) (actual time=0.042..0.066 rows=15 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (pt.track_id = ut.track_id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on playlist_tracks pt  (cost=0.00..32.60 rows=2260 width=8) (actual time=0.005..0.008 rows=18 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=38.25..38.25 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=10 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on user_tracks ut  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=4) (actual time=0.007..0.011 rows=10 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (user_id = 1)
 Planning Time: 0.215 ms
 Execution Time: 0.658 ms
(19 rows)
```

Having the following indexes in place will improve query performance significantly:

```
create index ut_user_id on user_tracks (user_id);
create index ut_track_id on user_tracks (track_id);
create index pt_track_id on playlist_tracks (track_id);
create index pt_playlist_id on playlist_tracks (playlist_id);
create index p_id on playlists (id);
```

Improved plan:

```
                                                                 QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=3.26..3.27 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.103..0.103 rows=5 loops=1)
   Sort Key: (count(1)) DESC
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=3.23..3.25 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.093..0.098 rows=5 loops=1)
         Group Key: p.id, p.title
         ->  Sort  (cost=3.23..3.24 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.087..0.089 rows=15 loops=1)
               Sort Key: p.id, p.title
               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
               ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.27..3.22 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.043..0.075 rows=15 loops=1)
                     ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.14..2.39 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.037..0.045 rows=15 loops=1)
                           Hash Cond: (pt.track_id = ut.track_id)
                           ->  Seq Scan on playlist_tracks pt  (cost=0.00..1.18 rows=18 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.010 rows=18 loops=1)
                           ->  Hash  (cost=1.12..1.12 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=10 loops=1)
                                 Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
                                 ->  Seq Scan on user_tracks ut  (cost=0.00..1.12 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.009 rows=10 loops=1)
                                       Filter: (user_id = 1)
                     ->  Index Scan using p_id on playlists p  (cost=0.13..0.82 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=15)
                           Index Cond: (id = pt.playlist_id)
 Planning Time: 0.505 ms
 Execution Time: 0.163 ms
(20 rows)
```

It returns the following result:

```
 id |              title
----+---------------------------------
  3 | Mojito Lounge
  2 | Kings & Queens of Blues Rock
  1 | Classic Rock's Greatest Hits
  4 | Dark Electro Lounging
  5 | Atmospheric Chilled Electronica
(5 rows)
```

**Does it look like something you would expect?**

If yes, here's how it can be translated to Ecto:

```
import Ecto.Query

user_id = 1

query =
  from p in "playlists",
    select: {p.id, p.title},
    join: pt in "playlist_tracks", on: pt.playlist_id == p.id,
    join: ut in "user_tracks", on: ut.track_id == pt.track_id,
    where: ut.user_id == ^user_id,
    group_by: [p.id, p.title],
    order_by: count(1)

MyRepo.all(query)
```

You should be able to adopt this example by:

- switching table name references like `playlists` and `user_tracks` for schemas, e.g. `Playlist` and `User.Track` respectively (assuming this is how your schema modules are called),
- changing `select: {p.id, p.title}` to `select: struct(p, [p.id, p.title])`, which will give you `Playlist` structs instead of tuples, if that's desired (**not** tested though).

---

Generally, unless the query has to be highly flexible (e.g. depend on many parameters determined at runtime) which is achieved by dynamically building it using Ecto, it should be perfectly fine to keep the query written in raw SQL.